# Draw log graph curve on Matlab by clicking?

Tags: matlab, graph, coordinates, draw, curve

I'd like to draw a curve on an empty (semilog-y) graph by clicking the points I want it to run through, on the X-Y plane.

Is there a function for this?

edit: I'm trying to do this by obtaining the position of last pointer click -

```
axis([0 3000 0 1000]); 
co=get(gcf, 'CurrentPoint');
```

It seems to return the cursor position at the time of execution, but it does not change later.

edit2: Here's what works for me. The actual drawing I can do by using the arrays of points collected.

```
clear
clc
h=plot(0);
grid on;

xlim([0 3000]);
ylim([0 1000]);
datacursormode on;

% Enlarge figure to full screen.
screenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');
set(gcf, 'units','pixels','outerposition', screenSize);
hold on;

% Print the x,y coordinates - will be in plot coordinates
x=zeros(1,10); y=zeros(1,10);
for p=1:10;

[x(p),y(p)] = ginput(1) ;

% Mark where they clicked with a cross.
plot(x(p),y(p), 'r+', 'MarkerSize', 20, 'LineWidth', 3);

% Print coordinates on the plot.
label = sprintf('(%.1f, %.1f)', x(p), y(p));
text(x(p)+20, y(p), label);

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but now there is:

```
function topLevel

    %// parameters
    xrange = [0 100];
    yrange = [1e-4 1e4];

    %// initialize figure, plot    
    figure, clf, hold on
    plot(NaN, NaN);
    axis([xrange yrange]);
    set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')
    t = text(sum(xrange)/2, sum(yrange)/2, ...
        '<< Need at least 3 points >>',...
        'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');

    %// Main loop
    xs = [];  p = [];
    ys = [];  P = [];
    while true

        %// Get new user-input, and collect all of them in a list
        [x,y] = ginput(1);
        xs = [xs; x]; %#ok<AGROW>
        ys = [ys; y]; %#ok<AGROW>

        %// Plot the selected points
        if ishandle(p)
            delete(p); end        
        p = plot(xs, ys, 'rx');
        axis([xrange yrange]);

        %// Fit curve through user-injected points
        if numel(xs) >= 3

            if ishandle(t)
                delete(t); end

            %// Get parameters of best-fit in a least-squares sense
            [A,B,C] = fitExponential(xs,ys);

            %// Plot the new curve
            xp = linspace(xrange(1), xrange(end), 100);
            yp = A + B*exp(C*xp);            
            if ishandle(P)
                delete(P); end
            P = plot(xp,yp, 'b');            

        end               
    end

    %// Fit a model of the form  y = A + B·exp(C·x)  to data [x,y]
    function [A, B, C] = fitExponential(x,y)

        options = optimset(...
            'maxfunevals', inf);

        A = fminsearch(@lsq, 0, options);
        [~,B,C] = lsq(A);

        function [val, B,C] = lsq(A)

            params = [ones(size(x(:))) x(:)] \ log(abs(y-A));

            B = exp(params(1));
            C = params(2);

            val = sum((y - A - B*exp(C*x)).^2);

        end

    end

end
```

Note that as always, fitting an exponential curve can be tricky; the square of the difference between model and data is exponentially much greater for higher data values than for lower data values, so there will be a strong bias to fit the higher values better than the lower ones.

I just assumed a simple model and used a simple solution, but this gives a biased curve which might not be "optimal" in the sense that you need it to be. Any **decent** solution really depends on what you want specifically, and I'll leave that up to you ^_^